# Getting Missing element from comparison of Array's using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368386/comparing-two-arrays-get-the-values-which-are-not-common)

I wanted a logic to get uncommon items from an array, for example:

```
$a=@(1,2,3,4,5,6)
$b=@(1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10)
```

I want the output `$c` to be 6 which is the missing element in `$b` array, priority should be only given to the array contents of `$a`.

Can anyone please help me out with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Check my comment on your previous question, you will find (with a little effort).

Comment: hi @stej im ujable to make it out!

Comment: hi @stej its not a duplicat question, i want preference to be given to array $a now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either empo's approach, or

```
$a1=@(1,2,3,4,5,8)
$b1=@(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Compare-Object $a1 $b1 | 
   Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | 
   Foreach-Object { $_.InputObject }
```

returns 8

Answer (score 4):

```
$c = $a | ? {!($b -contains $_)}
```

The priority will be given to the variable you "pipe".

Comment: You could also use: ?{$b -notcontains $_}

Comment: Or `? { -not ($b -contains $_) }`, the result is the same.