# Powershell Compare-Object Trouble

Tags: powershell

This is what I have but its not correct.

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\U0146121\Desktop\Output.txt) |
ForEach-Object {
Compare-Object -referenceobject $_ -DifferenceObject $(get-content C:\Users\U0146121\Desktop\New folder\filenames.txt) -IncludeEqual
}
```

I want to compare the current line and see if it is in the filenames.txt
If it is then write the name to a new txt file.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the loop.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content .\Two.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content .\One.txt) -IncludeEq
ual | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=='}  | Select -ExpandProperty InputObject | Out-file C:\same.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like similar to [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368386/comparing-two-arrays-get-the-values-which-are-not-common)

Drop each file's contents in a collection `$Ref = (Get-Content $origFile); $New = (Get-Content $NewFile);`. Make sure both lists contain the same level of path references (absolute paths vs relative with same depth). Then compare the two collection objects.