# Get all unused SessionHosts in a Remote Desktop Service Deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to get all not used SessionHosts in a RDS Deployment.

At the end of the code I get two lists with all SessionHosts and all used SessionHosts and these two lists I want to compare to get all unused hosts.

For the comparison, I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/6368667/6708104 .

```
# ALL SessionHosts
$RDSessionHost = (Get-RDserver -Role "RDS-RD-SERVER" -ConnectionBroker $ConnectionBrooker).Server
Write-Host "Alle SessionHosts:" -ForegroundColor Green

# All SessionCollections
$RDSessionCollections = (Get-RDSessionCollection -ConnectionBroker $ConnectionBrooker).Collectionname

# ALL used SessionHosts
foreach($p in $RDSessionCollections){
$used = (Get-RDSessionHost -CollectionName $p -ConnectionBroker $ConnectionBrooker).SessionHost
}

#ALL unused SessionHosts
$unused = ($RDSessionHost | Where {$used -NotContains $_})
```

**Result**

```
ALL SessionHosts:
SessionHost1
SessionHost2
SessionHost12
SessionHost11
SessionHost10
SessionHost9
SessionHost6
SessionHost8
SessionHost5
SessionHost3
SessionHost4
SessionHost7

ALL USED SessionHosts:
SessionHost1
SessionHost2
SessionHost11
SessionHost10
SessionHost9
SessionHost6
SessionHost7
SessionHost5
SessionHost4
SessionHost3

ALL UNUSED SessionHosts:
SessionHost1
SessionHost2
SessionHost12
SessionHost11
SessionHost10
SessionHost9
SessionHost6
SessionHost8
SessionHost5
SessionHost3
SessionHost4
SessionHost7
```

But there are only two unused: SessionHost8 and SessionHost12

Comment: And what is your problem? Error?

Comment: The comparison is not working.

Comment: You should use a property like `Name` in your where-object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find items in one `array` those are not in another `array` you should use `Where-Object` cmdlet and comparisson operator such as `-contains` or `-notcontains`. Like so:

```
$array1 = @('A','B','C','D','E','F')
$array2 = @('A','B','F')
$array1 | Where-Object {$array2 -notcontains $_ }
C
D
E
```

Also, in your code `$used` variable will always contain just one item because you are overwriting its value on every foreach loop.

```
# ALL used SessionHosts
foreach($p in $RDSessionCollections){
$used = (Get-RDSessionHost -CollectionName $p -ConnectionBroker $ConnectionBrooker).SessionHost
}
```

You would want to create an `array variable` explicitly and add used hosts values into.

```
# ALL used SessionHosts
$used = @()
foreach($p in $RDSessionCollections){
$used += (Get-RDSessionHost -CollectionName $p -ConnectionBroker $ConnectionBrooker).SessionHost
}
```

And for filtering unused SessionHosts you probably want to use `$RDSessionCollections`

```
$unused = ($RDSessionCollections| Where {$used -NotContains $_})
```

instead of `$RDSessionHost`

```
$unused = ($RDSessionHost | Where {$used -NotContains $_})
```