# Powershell Compare-Object output to file

Tags: powershell

I have 2 simple text files that I need to compare and output the items that are in BOTH files

Archive.TXT

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
10005
10010
10011
```

Active-Job-List.TXT

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
10006
10007
10008
10009
10010
10011
10012
```

This will give me an output

```
$File1 = Get-Content C:\Archive-List.txt
$File2 = Get-Content C:\Active-Job-List.txt



   Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $File1 -DifferenceObject $File2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | Select @{Expression={$_.InputObject}} | Set-Content C:\Diff.txt
```

of this in the Diff.txt

```
@{$_.InputObject=10000}
@{$_.InputObject=10001}
@{$_.InputObject=10002}
@{$_.InputObject=10003}
@{$_.InputObject=10005}
@{$_.InputObject=10010}
@{$_.InputObject=10011}
```

But what I am really looking for is an output of this

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
10005
10010
10011
```

How can I filter the results to what I want? Should I `Get-Content` of the Diff.txt and "trim" out things I don't want or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Instead of `Select @{Expression={$_.InputObject}}` use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject`

Comment: `$File1 | Where {$File2 -Contains $_}`, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026

Answer (score 4):

You need to *expand* the `InputObject` property.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $File1 -DifferenceObject $File2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject | 
    Set-Content C:\Diff.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `-PassThru` to your command like so:

`Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $File1 -DifferenceObject $File2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Set-Content C:\Diff.txt`