# Removing elements from one array, using the elements in another(closed)

Tags: powershell

I realize arrays are fixed-size collections. I am aware of how to manipulate their contents in various ways, change them into other array types, etc, but I can't figure out how to use the contents of one array to remove elements from another. For example, lets say we have this array:

```
$keep = "string1" , "string2" , "string3"
```

Then we build another array from something like a directory:

```
$collection = (get-childItem c:\directory1).Name
```

Now I want to make a third array by removing the three elements found in $keep from $collection:

```
$collection2 = $collection | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $keep}
```

I cannot seem to get this to work. Lets just assume both of the first two arrays here are type object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368386/comparing-two-arrays-get-the-values-which-are-not-common/35872835)

You could use something like this:

```
$keep = "1","2","3"
$list = "1","2","3","4","5","6"

$final = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $list -DifferenceObject $keep
```