# In powershell, how to test in an array already contains an object with all the same properties?

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I want to avoid inserting duplicates into an array in powershell. Trying to use `-notcontains` doesn't seem to work with a `PSCUstomObject` array.

Here's a code sample

```
$x = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = 111
    bar = 222
}

$y = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = 111
    bar = 222
}

$collection = @()

$collection += $x

if ($collection -notcontains $y){
    $collection += $y
}


$collection.Count #Expecting to only get 1, getting 2
```

Comment: The answer is effectively the same as i [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026) except that you don't care about the results only whether there is any result: (`@($collection).count`, you will need to **force an array** otherwise you counting characters in case of a singleton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6) for this.

```
$x = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = 111
    bar = 222
}

$y = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = 111
    bar = 222
}
$collection = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()

[void]$collection.Add($x)

if (Compare-Object -Ref $collection -Dif $y -Property foo,bar | Where SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
    [void]$collection.Add($y)
}
```

**Explanation:**

Comparing a custom object to another using [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) is not trivial. This solution compares the particular properties you care about (`foo` and `bar` in this case). This can be done simply with `Compare-Object`, which will output differences in either object by default. The `SideIndicator` value of `=>` indicates the difference lies in the object passed into the `-Difference` parameter.

The `[System.Collections.Arraylist]` type is used over an array to avoid the inefficient `+=` typically seen when growing an array. Since the `.Add()` method produces an output of the index being modified, the `[void]` cast is used to suppress that output.

---

You could be dynamic with the solution regarding the properties. You may not want to hard code the property names into the `Compare-Object` command. You can do something like the following instead.

```
$x = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = 111
    bar = 222
}

$y = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = 111
    bar = 222
}
$collection = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()

[void]$collection.Add($x)
$properties = $collection[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
                  Select-Object -Expand Name

if (Compare-Object -Ref $collection -Dif $y -Property $properties | Where SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
    [void]$collection.Add($y)
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. And thank you for offering a solution on how not to hardcode property names.