# compare two csv files, missing expected results in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I have two csv files, one that contains a list of the MySQL 8.0 reserved keywords and another that contains four randomly chosen reserved keywords as well as test1, test2, test3 and test 4. I want to compare the two csv files, and return results that are present in both files. The test csv file contains first_value, rank, savepoint, shutdown, test1, test2, test3, and test4 [screenshot of entries in csv file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdS7c.png) For some reason, my script is only returning savepoint and shutdown instead of savepoint, shutdown, rank and first_value. I'm not sure why? I'd appreciate any thoughts!!

Results of script:
[you can see savepoint and shutdown are present in both in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3D80.png)

```
    $array_list = @()
foreach($row in (Get-Content C:\ShowStopper\test3.csv)){
    $array_list += ($row.split(','))
}
$array_list

$array_list2 = @()
foreach($row in (Get-Content C:\ShowStopper\80.csv)){
    $array_list2 += ($row.split(','))
}
$array_list2

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $array_list2 -DifferenceObject $array_list -IncludeEqual
```

I also tried a simpler variation, which did not work either.

```
$objects = @{
ReferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path C:\ShowStopper\test3.csv)
DifferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path C:\ShowStopper\80.csv)
}

Compare-Object @objects -IncludeEqual
```

Comment: There are special cmdlets for the import (and export) of csv files. Surprisingly they are called [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1) and [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1). But watch out for the Headers.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried changing it to use Import-CSV, and I'm still only receiving savepoint and shutdown as equal results... 
`$tablenames = Import-CSV -Path "C:\ShowStopper\test3.csv" | Select -ExpandProperty 'Table Name'
$tablenames

$keywords = Import-CSV "C:\ShowStopper\80.csv" | Select -ExpandProperty 'Table Name'
$keywords

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $tablenames -DifferenceObject $keywords -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent` is the updated code I tried.

Comment: If you want to compare an array of objects, remove the `-ExpandProperty`. If you want to compare an array of strings, see: [Compare two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a hidden whitespace or something like that in one of the CSVs? Maybe try an other tool to compare the CSVs manually. E.g. Notepad++ with the compare addon to visualize the matches

Comment: @T-Me thank you for that idea, another coworker tried the various codes as well and that's the conclusion he has reached also.. working now to identify the culprit. Thank you!