# how to get the variable which is not entered to if loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, loops

the below is the code ,in which I am comparing values.

```
 $b=100
 $c=100,200,300
  foreach ($vvv in $c){

if($vvv -eq $b)
   {
  Write-Host $vvv
}
   Write-Host $vvv "value"
  }
```

Result
the output for the above code is

```
  100
  100 value
  200 value
  300 value
```

but the requirement here is I don't want to use the else loop here ,and I need the value which is not entering to the if loop

```
 The output I need is 
  200
  300
```

Comment: Just: `$c -ne $b`, see: [**When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#common-features)

Comment: My requirement is i need "the variable value which is not executing in if loop " .If i change the operator (equal to  or anything ). i just only need the value which is not executing in the if loop ,with out using the Else

Answer (score 1):

The below will give out the expected results, where values in `$c` array are not in `$b` array.

```
$b=100
$c=100,200,300

$Results = $C | Where {$_ -notin $b}

$Results
```

Comment: As commented in the question, there is no reason to use expensive long-winded (cmdlet) iterators as [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) for this, just: `$Results = $c -ne $b`

Comment: @iRon - If you change `$b=100` to `$b=100,300`, the result will be 100,200,300. I think the OP is trying to understand how to compare one array against another. If they extend the comparing array the example you have given will not work.

Comment: In that case, it is probably a duplicate with [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026)