# Compare A and B list and create a C list with B values not in A list in Powershell

Tags: arrays, list, powershell

I have two list, A and B and I needed the element of the B list not present in the A list to be in a created list C in Powershell.
(list or array)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | One | Second |
| Two | Two |  |
| Three | Three |  |
| Third | Second |  |
| Fourth | third |  |

In this example in C there is the word Second as it is not present in A list.
So it is not the difference between two list, it is one to another, but not the other way around.

I have tested the `Compare-Object` command but it will exclude the element that are not in B but in A and the ones that are in B but not in A. Which is not what I am looking for.
I also tried something like this :

```
foreach ($elem in $A) { if ($B -contains $elem) { "there is a match" } }
```

But it didn't work as I want.

I'm a bit lost a this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368386/comparing-two-arrays-get-the-values-which-are-not-common)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I decided to use the following command:

```
Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ReferenceObject $A -DifferenceObject $B
```

With the side indicator, I could manage my third table the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-notin` operator:

```
$C = @($B) -notin $A
```

Supplying an enumerable left-hand operand to a scalar comparison operator like `-notin` turns the operator into a *filter* - and suddenly it works just like `$B |Where-Object { $_ -notin $A }`

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing differently, but I am not seeing that  behavior.  When I do `@($B) -notin $A` I just get `True`