# Check if the Servernames are in both Arrays

Tags: powershell

Hey guys I have a little problem. I'm doing a Script where I get all the Servers in our Activ Directory Server and then compare them with all the servers that are in our ESX Servers. I want to find out which Servers are in the Active Directory that are not in the ESX Array. Both Arays have the Option "name" with what I'm trying to compair the two Arrays.

I tried doing it with foreach but couldn't get it to work. Can somebody help?

Comment: `@(Compare-Object $AdServers $EsxServers).Count -eq 0` If this returns `$true` both arrays have the same elements

Comment: Please take some time to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and check for similar questions like: [powershell compare arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+compare+arrays)

Comment: @Theo Ah Okay thanks for the Comment.  But I would like to have the Servers that are not in both Arrays as output in the Commandline

Comment: Then do `Compare-Object $AdServers $EsxServers -PassThru`

Comment: See also: [Compare A and B list and create a C list with B values not in A list in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66887066/1701026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = 1..5
$b = 4..8

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b | Where-Object{$_ -match "<="}
```

Comment: This only returns elements that are in array `$a` but not in array `$b`, not vice-versa

Comment: ```$a = 1..5
$b = 4..8

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b ```

Comment: Thank you very much that works perfectly for me. @Theo I don't need it the otherway arround aswell, cause we also have Linux Servers which are not in the AD.

Comment: No, you still need switch `-PassThru` to obtain an array of just the server names