# Find what is different in two very large lists

Tags: powershell, set-difference, compareobject

I have two lists about 1k people each list.
What I want to do is find who is leftover between the two.

```
$BunchoEmail = Import-Csv C:\temp\Directory.csv | Select-Object primaryEmail -ExpandProperty primaryEmail

$GoogleUsers = gam print users fields suspended | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object suspended -ne $true | Select-Object primaryEmail -ExpandProperty primaryEmail

$objects = @{
    ReferenceObject  = $GoogleUsers
    DifferenceObject = $BunchoEmail
}
Compare-Object @objects
```

Above didn't produce what I wanted.

What is the best way to find what is different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load each list into a `[hashtable]`:

```
$emailTable = @{}
$BunchoEmail |ForEach-Object { $emailTable[$_] = $_ }

$gsuiteTable = @{}
$GoogleUsers |ForEach-Object { $gsuiteTable[$_] = $_ }
```

Now you can iterate over one list and check whether the other doesn't contain any particular email addresses with `Where-Object`:

```
$notInGSuite = $BunchoEmail |Where-Object { -not $gsuiteTable.ContainsKey($_) }

$notInEmailList = $GoogleUsers |Where-Object { -not $emailTable.ContainsKey($_) }
```

The time complexity of `ContainsKey()` on a hashtable is O(1), so it'll keep working for lists with 1000s of emails

Answer (score 6):

**[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)** is capable of finding what elements are missing from one collection relative to the other, vice versa, or both.

However, it **can be *slow***, and given that you mention *large* lists, it sounds like you're looking for a solution that performs well.

- However, **collections with 1,000 items are likely *not* a problem in practice**.
- Something like the following may therefore be sufficient to get all entries in `$BunchoEmail` that aren't also in `$GoogleUsers` (substitute `=>` for `<=` to reverse the logic):

  ```
  (Compare-Object -PassThru $BunchoEmail $GoogleUsers).
    Where({ $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' })
  ```
- Getting those entries that aren't in *both* collections (that are unique to *either* collection) is even easier:

  ```
  Compare-Object -PassThru $BunchoEmail $GoogleUsers
  ```

---

As for **improving performance**:

Combining type [`` [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1] ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) with LINQ enables a fast and concise solution:

Note:

- Use of `HashSet` implies that the results are reported in no particular order; to get them in *sorted* order, use [`[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet-1) instead. (There is no built-in type for maintaining the *insertion order* as of .NET 6).
- The solutions below are true *set* operations, i.e. they report *distinct* differences, unlike `Compare-Object`. E.g., if unique email `foo@example.org` is present *twice* in a collection, the solutions below report it only *once*, whereas `Compare-Object` reports both instances.
- Unlike `Compare-Object`, the `HashSet` and `SortedSet` types are case-*sensitive* by default; you can pass an equality comparer to the constructor for case-*insensitive* behavior, using [`System.StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.StringComparer); e.g.:

  ```
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] ('foo', 'FOO'),
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
  )
  ```

To get all entries in `$BunchoEmail` that aren't also in `$GoogleUsers`, use [`[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Except) (reverse the operands for the inverse solution):

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Except(
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $BunchoEmail,
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $GoogleUsers
)
```

<sup>Note: You could also use a hash set's `.ExceptWith()` method, but that requires storing one of the hash sets in an auxiliary variable, which is then updated *in place* - analogous to the `.SymmetricExceptWith()` solution below.</sup>

Getting those entries that aren't in *both* collections (that are unique to *either* collection, called the *symmetric difference* in set terms) requires a bit more effort, using a hash set's `.SymmetricExceptWith()` method:

```
# Load one of the collections into an auxiliary hash set.
$auxHashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $BunchoEmail

# Determine the symmetric difference between the two sets, which
# updates the calling set in place.
$auxHashSet.SymmetricExceptWith(
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $GoogleUsers
)

# Output the result
$auxHashSet
```

Comment: This is perfect, just noticed that `[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]` can also handle duplicated items in the collection without any exception thrown which is very nice.

Comment: Indeed, @SantiagoSquarzon, it creates a true set, and you can also call `.Add()` repeatedly without getting an exception (the `[bool]` return value indicates whether the element was already present).

Comment: Excellent question, @SantiagoSquarzon: you can - please see my update.