# Compare two CSV Files and output existing equalities

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

Im basically comparing an short list of PC names with our active directory, the first file is the list of pcs i have to check, the second file is the ad list that i got with following command

```
$ADcomputer = get-adcomputer -Filter "name -Like '*'" -Searchbase "DC=**,DC=******,DC=**"

($ADcomputer).name | Out-file "C:\temp\ADComputer.csv"
```

In both lists there are only pc names in split "A" most of them are built like "PC23425" just with various numbers (there are some exceptions of course but i dont need to check for them only for pcs with this pattern).

The list.csv is built like this

```
PC020682
PC020891
PC020953
PC021999
```

I read several posts about this and im very sure i need to use a foreach loop for that, but since i dont use powershell very often i aint sure how to pull it off.

What i try is

```
$Path = "C:\temp"
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path "$($path)\ADcomputer.csv"
$ComputerAchiv = Import-Csv -Path "$($path)\List.csv"
```

But i have no idea how to build the foreach loop.

Comment: This line `($ADcomputer).name | Out-file ...` creates not a CSV file, but a text file instead where all pc names are listed each on a separate line. Therefore there is no `"Row A"`. How is the second file created?? Is that not a CSV file as well? Open your `List.csv` file in notepad and copy the first 3 or 4 lines. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69617533/edit) your question and paste that in there.

Comment: @Theo yes the second file is also CSV, but i dont know how it was created since it was only send to me. I tried ```Export-CSV``` for the AD list but like that i only got the sting lenghts from the names and not the names.

Comment: `Get-Content "$($path)\List.csv" |Where-Object { $ADcomputer.name -eq $_ }`

Comment: @iRon thank you very much, thats exacly what i needed, also with out an foreach loop which just would took longer.

Comment: Glad iRon could help you, but you should really look into what makes a CSV file a structured CSV file and what the difference is between such a file and a simple text file. This could help you decide whether to use `Import-Csv` or `Get-Content`

Comment: @iRon Please post as answer.

Comment: As noted in the initial comment: If a file contains a list of names but doesn't contain an initial line containing a property name, then **it is not a CSV file**. It's just a text file. As noted in another comment, if (or because, in this case) you do not have a CSV file, then you would use `Get-Content` rather than `Import-Csv` (because again, it is not a CSV file but rather just a plain text file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a [`CSV` file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is not fully standardized, as mentioned by [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) PowerShell expects the first row to be the header record by default. The header row will be used to define the property names of the object(s) eventually emitted by the [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) cmdlet. In the case your `CSV` file doesn't contain a header row, you might manually add the header row (column names, property names) by using the `-Header` parameter, e.g.: `-Header username`.
For PowerShell you files are simple lists (without properties), which you might read using the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet:

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content -Path "$($path)\ADcomputer.csv"
$ComputerAchiv = Get-Content -Path "$($path)\List.csv"
```

To find out the items that the lists share, you might use the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet:
<sup>(see also: [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026))</sup>

```
$ComputerList |Where-Object { $ADcomputer.name -eq $_ }
```

### Next Level

Although this might be a direct answer to your question. It might not bring you much as you probably *do* want to deal with PowerShell standard CSV files (Meaning PowerShell object lists) and join those. For this, see e.g.: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)