# Compare txt files - Powershell

Tags: powershell, compare, txt

I have two txt files. Both contain a list of usernames:

List 1:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

List 2:

```
user1
user2
user7
```

I want to compare these two lists. I want to know which users do not exist in both lists.
So the output in this case should be a this list:

Endlist:

```
user3
user7
```

This is my code:

```
$list1 = get-content -Path "C:\list1.txt"
$list2 = get-content -Path "C:\list2.txt"

$endlist = foreach ($item in $list1) 
{
       if ($item -notmatch $list2)
       {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $item 
       }

}
$endlist |Out-file "C:\endlist.txt"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see also: [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6368386)

Comment: Please pick the answer that best solves your problem and click the big ✓ to the left of it to _accept_ it. This helps future visitors that have a similar problem to quickly find the "best" answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.2) for this:

```
$list1 = 'user1', 'user2', 'user3'
$list2 = 'user1', 'user2', 'user7'

(Compare-Object $list1 $list2).InputObject # => user3, user7
```

If you want to do the comparison manually, and since you want to know the objects unique to either list, you would need *two* loops and the use of a [containment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) (`-notin` or `-notcontains` in this case):

```
$list1 = (Get-Content list1.txt).Trim()
$list2 = (Get-Content list2.txt).Trim()

& {
    foreach($i in $list1) {
        if($i -notin $list2) { $i }
    }
    foreach($i in $list2) {
        if($i -notin $list1) { $i }
    }
} | Out-File "endlist.txt"
```

Comment: But if I just want to know which objects  from list1 are not in list2, I tried this:                                $result = foreach ($item in $list1){ if($item -notin $list2){[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$item}}} ... the result file shows just all users from list1 but not the users who are in list1 but not in list2 ... Why?

Comment: @user18209625 my only guess is that `$list2` is not defined. Or you have not provided an actual representation of the contents of your files

Comment: $list 2 is defined. Could it be a problem that my objects are not quoted? My txt is like this: user1 user2 user3 (with a new line between every user)

Comment: @user18209625 see the update using `Trim()` on the lists, aside from that I have no idea what could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the existing working solutions, here is another one using a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0), which might be faster than `Compare-Object`:

```sh
[Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $list1 = Get-Content list1.txt
[Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $list2 = Get-Content list2.txt

$list1.SymmetricExceptWith($list2)
$list1
```

Output:

```
user7
user3
```

`HashSet`'s strangely named<sup>1</sup> [`SymmetricExceptWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=net-6.0) method **modifies** the first set to contain only those elements that are unique to either set.

<sup>1) The mathematical term is [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use compare-object

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $list1 -DifferenceObject $list2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```