# Powershell filtering one list out of another list

Tags: powershell, filter

> <updated, added *Santiago Squarzon* suggest information>

I have two lists, I pull them from csv but there is only one column in each of the two lists.
Here is how I pull in the lists in my script

```
$orginal_list = Get-Content -Path .\random-word-350k-wo-quotes.txt
$filter_words = Get-Content -Path .\no_go_words.txt
```

However, I will use a typed list for simplicity in the code example below.

In this example, the **$original_list** can have some words repeated.
I want to filter out all of the words in **$original_list** that are in the **$filter_words** list.

Then add the filtered list to the variable **$filtered_list**.
In this example, **$filtered_list** would only have `"dirt","turtle"` in it.
I know the line I have below where I subtract the two won't work, it's there as a placeholder as I don't know what to use to get the result.

Of note, the csv file that feeds **$original_list** could have *300,000* or more rows, and **$filter_words** could have *hundreds* of rows. So would want this to be as efficient as possible.
The filtering is **case insensitive**.

```
$orginal_list = "yellow","blue","yellow","dirt","blue","yellow","turtle","dirt"
$filter_words = "yellow","blue","green","harsh"

$filtered_list = $orginal_list - $filter_words

$filtered_list

dirt
turtle
```

Comment: `$orginal_list|where{$_ -notin $filter_words}|select -Unique` will do what you want

Comment: you should include how do you acquire both lists, using mklement0's answer with `ExceptWith( )` but you should use pipeline processing for an efficient filtering. you should also include if case sensitivity is important

Comment: **TheMadTechnician**  
This works and builds the list into the variable when I add **$filtered_list =** in front.  But it is **very slow** when working on >300,000 records.

Comment: Using this general [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)), whether you use an object (with properties) list or a scalar list: `$filtered_list = $orginal_list |OuterJoin $filter_words` or using the PowerShell pipeline: `Import-Csv .\Orginal.csv |OuterJoin $filter_words |...`

Comment: See also: [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`` System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) and its [`.ExceptWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1.ExceptWith) method:

```bash
# Note: if possible, declare the lists as [string[]] arrays to begin with.
#       Otherwise, use a [string[]] cast im the method calls below, which,
#       however, creates a duplicate array on the fly.
[string[]] $orginal_list = "yellow","blue","yellow","dirt","blue","yellow","turtle","dirt"
[string[]] $filter_words = "yellow","blue","green","harsh"

# Create a hash set based on the strings in $orginal_list,
# with case-insensitive lookups.
$hsOrig = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
  $orginal_list,
  [System.StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
)

# Reduce it to those strings not present in $filter_words, in-place.
$hsOrig.ExceptWith($filter_words)

# Convert the filtered hash set to an array.
[string[]] $filtered_list = [string[]]::new($hsOrig.Count)
$hsOrig.CopyTo($filtered_list)

# Output the result
$filtered_list
```

The above yields:

```bash
dirt
turtle
```

---

To also speed up reading your input files, use the following:

```bash
# Note: System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines() returns a [string[]] instance.
$orginal_list = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines((Convert-Path .\random-word-350k-wo-quotes.txt))
$filter_words = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines((Convert-Path .\no_go_words.txt))
```

Note:

- .NET generally defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8; pass a `[System.Text.Encoding]` instance as a second argument, if needed.
- .NET's working dir. usually differs from PowerShell's, so the use of *full* paths is always advisable in .NET API calls, and that is what the [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) calls ensure.

Comment: **mklement0**  Your updates worked perfect.  And the tip on loading up the files quicker was insanely faster, old method was TotalMilliseconds : 10079.7768  your suggested method was TotalMilliseconds : 117.5378.  Thank you for that.
     I want to close this, however as is most cases here. I was given a curve ball last minute.  I do not want to add on to this ticket. I will close this as answered and open a new one.  They now want to pick words that are equal to or between a length, so min=4 max=9. They gave me a csv file that has two columns, **Word**, **Length**. Will put in new ticket. TY

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Rugbyball; yeah, `Get-Content` performs poorly (unless you use `-Raw` to read the file _as a whole_ or use `-ReadCount` to read it in _chunks_).

Answer (score 2):

I have found that using [Linq](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/high-performance-powershell-linq/#post-71022-_Toc482783761) to filter one list out from another is incredibly easy and incredibly fast (especially for large lists)

```
# ARRAY OF 1000 STRINGS LOWERCASE (item1 - item1000)
[string[]]$ThousandItems = 1..1000 | %{"item$_"};

# ARRAY OF 100 STRINGS UPPERCASE (ITEM901 - ITEM1000)
[string[]]$HundredItems = 901..1000 | %{"ITEM$_"};

# SUBTRACT THE SECOND ARRAY FROM THE FIRST ONE (CASE INSENSITIVELY)
[string[]]$NineHundred = [Linq.Enumerable]::Except($ThousandItems, $HundredItems, [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase);
$NineHundred;
```

Which returns the list of 1000 items minus Item901-Item1000

```
item1
item2
...
item899
item900
```

As for speed, removing 100 items from a list...

```
     1,000 Items =     1ms
    10,000 Items =     2ms
   100,000 Items =    12ms
 1,000,000 Items =   259ms
10,000,000 Items = 3,008ms
```

**Note**: These times are just on the [`[Linq.Enumerable]::Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0) line.  So it's just measuring the time taken to subtract one array from the other.  It does not measure the time taken to fill the array.

So to apply this to the original poster's example

```
$original_list = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines((Convert-Path .\random-word-350k-wo-quotes.txt));
$filter_words = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines((Convert-Path .\no_go_words.txt));
[string[]]$filtered_list = [Linq.Enumerable]::Except($original_list,$filter_words,[System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

For this, I literally inserted 350K strings (the MD5 hash of the numbers 1 - 350K) into the original list (uppercase), inserted 10K strings (the MD5 hash of the numbers 1-10K) into the filter words list (lowercase) and ran that code.

There were 340K words in the filtered list, and it only took **260ms** to read both files, filter and return the list

Comment: nicely done. love this answer :)